# Can you change the selected page in WatchKit PageView

Tags: watchkit

Imagine I have 5 pages, If I'm on page 1 can I programmatically load page 5?

I'm aware of using becomeCurrentPage to load the initial page but not of how to switch it (if at all possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send post an `NSNotificaton` whenever you want to switch and have your desired InterfaceController as an observer for this notification. And inside the selector of the observer. call `[self beconmeCurrentPage]`. It worked for me and i hope it works for you as well.

Comment: I ended up changing the flow of the app a bit but I imagine this would work!

Comment: Could you please give me specific demo source code ? I'm trying to do like that but dont know how to do?

Comment: I am glad it worked. Sorry for not replying sooner. :)