# WatchKit Page-based navigation

Tags: swift, watchkit

I am trying to programmatically move to a page with a page-based navigation, but this does not seems to be possible?

I have tried to use the `pushControllerWithName:context:`, but it only works for hierarchical based navigation.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you want page based navigation (for one or multiple pages) without implementing the segues in storyboard at compile time???

Comment: I have multiple interfacecontrollers/pages WITH the segues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send post an NSNotificaton whenever you want to switch and have your desired InterfaceController as an observer for this notification. And inside the selector of the observer. call `[self beconmeCurrentPage]`. It worked for me and i hope it works for you as well.

Quoted from a previous answer: [Can you change the selected page in WatchKit PageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023986/can-you-change-the-selected-page-in-watchkit-pageview/29027508#29027508)

Comment: I thought about this solution, but it is kind of weird to do it like this? But good to know it works! Do you know if there are any other ways to do it?